# Create a mask array, where `1` are at max value index of given array

Tags: julia

Given a matrix `A = [1 5 3; 4 2 6]`. How to create a new mask matrix where `1` values are at column-wise maximum value index `mask = [0 1 0; 1 0 1]`. How to do this in julia without mutating any created arrays.

With mutation I'm doing it the following way.

```
maxval, maxind = findmax(A, dims=1)
mask = zeros(size(A))
mask[maxind] .= 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really nothing wrong with what you have (although I'd probably use `falses` instead of `zeros`).  You could alternatively use broadcast, but I'd expect it to have similar performance:

```
julia> A = [1 5 3; 4 2 6]
2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  5  3
 4  2  6

julia> A .== maximum(A, dims=1)
2×3 BitArray{2}:
 0  1  0
 1  0  1
```

(Note that unlike Python, we differentiate between matrices and vectors of vectors; you wrote them like the latter)